# Google Cloud Messaging Registration TIMEOUT

Tags: java, android, timeout, google-cloud-messaging, registration

I've chosen Google Cloud Messaging for my application, which is so far working perfectly on Google APIs 17,18, 19 & 21. However, on Google APIs 16, I get a TIMEOUT at registration level. Has anyone faced this before ? I am using an AsyncTask as recommended by Google.

My code:

```
private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // before making http calls         
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

try{

    // ...

    // register device to Google Cloud Messaging if not already done
    if(gcmDeviceRegID.equals("")){
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        gcmDeviceRegID = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
    }

}

catch( Exception e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}

return null;

}

//...
```

The log:

```
W/InstanceID/Rpc(887): Found 10016
W/InstanceID/Rpc(887): No response android.os.ConditionVariable@41206630
W/System.err(887): java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT
W/System.err(887):  at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
W/System.err(887):  at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
W/System.err(887):  at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
W/System.err(887):  at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
W/System.err(887):  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
W/System.err(887):  at com.domain.appname.SplashScreenActivity$PrefetchData.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:104)
W/System.err(887):  at com.domain.appname.SplashScreenActivity$PrefetchData.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:1)
W/System.err(887):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
W/System.err(887):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/System.err(887):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/System.err(887):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
W/System.err(887):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
```

As you understand, SplashScreenActivity.java:104 is this line:

```
gcmDeviceRegID = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
```

Any idea how to solve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: This way of getting an application identifier is not recommended. Could you try it with InstanceID.getToken() as described in the following link and see if you are still getting the same issue?

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java

Comment: Yes it works with this method, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Arthur Thompson's comment, this is being solved by using the new recommended way to register to GCM (starting from 2015, June 28):

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
gcmDeviceRegID = instanceID.getToken(PROJECT_NUMBER,GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

instead of

```
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
gcmDeviceRegID = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
```

Useful links:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration

Thanks & Regards